# Use Beamer package with Get package

Tags: dart, flutter-getx, flutter-beamer

In general everything works for me, nevertheless I get an error in my console regarding Getx & Beamer types

> Expected a value of type 'GetNavConfig', but got one of type 'RouteInformation'

I think that I know where the RouteInformation comes from:

```
  List<BeamPage> buildPages(
  BuildContext context, RouteInformationSerializable state) {
return [HomePage.beamLocation];
```

}

it is an argument of the `buildPages()` method, that has to be implemented due to the abstract `Beamer` class.

On the other hand I think that the

```
GetMaterialApp
```

expects a GetNavConfig, but gets a RouteInformation. I'm not really sure whether the things that I interpreted are correct. So I have no idea how to do something against the error. How could I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you're trying to rely on the beamer package instead of the `Getx` routing management feature, then you do not need the `GetMaterialApp`, you need to just use the `MaterialApp`, and for the beamer you need to use the `MaterialApp.router`.

`Getx` is a package that offers separate features, you could get state management and dependency injection... working fine without `GetMaterialApp`.

However, this means that you will not be allowed to use navigation methods such as `Get.to()` and `Get.toNamed()`, you cannot use the `Get.context`, and you cannot use the `Getx`'s bottom sheet and dialogs.

Comment: My problem is that I use some GetX features like GetX SnackBar

Comment: I would just say that trying to mix the Getx route management feature with other routing packages will definitely get you some errors in the future, I recommend to dedicate yourself to use one of them, not both, for snack bars, you could use some other separate package for it.